# Next image with fixed height and full width

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need fixed height, full width next/image (imagine a horizontal stripe image). I could wrap it in a div with `position="relative"`, fixed height and full width, and use `layout="fill"` on the image itself. However, this way I would still have to fetch full size image (that's what happens with layout fill). What is the most performance optimal way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider that nextjs has no idea what size the image will be displayed at runtime. The user agent will check if a `srcset` attribute exists and fetch the image from the matching URL.

From the documentation it looks like this can be achieved in NextJs by [setting device sizes and image sizes as appropriate](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#device-sizes)